# Splice dosen't work in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, foreach, ionic-framework

When i try to splice my array, it removes the wrong ones, i think its somthing to with the index of forEach when spliceing..
Tried for hours now and can't get it to work :/

```
     dpd.users.get(function (result) {
        $scope.persons = result;

            $scope.persons.forEach(function(entry, index) {
                dpd.timesheets.get({user:entry.id}, function (result2) {

                entry.timesheets = result2;

            //splice person if timesheets of person is empty

                if (entry.timesheets.length <=0){
                   $scope.persons.splice(index, 1);
                }
```

......................

Comment: Nothing will happen if you just splice it. You need to assign the retun to a variable. Like: `$scope.persons = $scope.persons.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: @CoryDanielson: In JavaScript, `splice` modifies the array in-place. (Unlike, say, `slice` or `map` or `filter`.) Does angular make this not the normal `Array#splice`? You *really* wouldn't want to assign the usual return value of `splice` to the original variable; `splice` returns an array of the elements that were removed.

Comment: actually I tried it and it works with me. and It's as mentioned in previous comments update the array inplace. http://plnkr.co/edit/13Z4hoqOAzIJBCa58rSX?p=preview

Comment: you're splicing the array you're iterating over in the middle of a forEach loop ... that's bound to cause problems

Comment: @sgroves: Good point. The behavior is well-defined, but that doesn't mean it isn't confusing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, you could totally do this, but i wouldn't. make a note of the indexes to splice out and then splice them after the forEach loop. or use `Array.filter` or something.

Comment: This should work perfectly. You better check your conditions and flow. Start with logging which ones are removed by adding a console.log(entry) line in if block.

Comment: Whoops. I typo'd my test for splice and used `slice` on accident. splice does modify the original array. slice does not.